# How to Import Classes from Reference Library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to both Java and to the Eclipse IDE, and I am having trouble with adding a Referenced Library and actually using it in my code.

I am in a software testing class, and my assignment is to use the JWebUnit library to run some basic tests on a website of my choice.  I have downloaded a zip of the library and added it to the build path, so that it shows up in my Referenced Libraries list.

[image: My Referenced Libraries list]

When I try to actually use that library, though, the import statement gives an error.

[image: Import statement error]

I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong that the base class cannot see this library.

Comment: Did you try using fix project setup?

Comment: The screenshot show that you have added the folder `net` (not a `.zip` file) as class folder to the _Java Build Path_. If that folder contains `*.class` files, you must add the parent folder of `net` to the _Java Build Path_. Otherwise (if no `*.class` files are contained, but e.g. `*.java` or `*.html` files), you downloaded the wrong thing. Usually a `.jar` file will be provided which can be added to the _Java Build Path_ without unzipping it.

Comment: @howlger That's exactly what I did - the version I downloaded had only `.java` and `.html` files.

Comment: That's the source code and Javadoc and not executable Java code (`.class` files). I guess you have to download e.g. `jwebunit-3.3-release.zip` from [here](https://github.com/JWebUnit/jwebunit/releases) and add all JARs contained in that ZIP (in the root folder and in `lib`) to your _Java Build Path_.

Comment: @howlger I did exactly that as soon as I read your first comment and it worked like a dream.  You were right on the money.  If you want, copy this last comment and put it as an answer, and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot show that you have added the folder `net` as class folder to the *Java Build Path*. Maybe you have added the **source code** (`.java` files) **or Javadoc** (`.html` files) **instead of the executable bytecode** (`.class` files).  Usually `.jar` files are provided containing `.class` files which can directly be added to the *Java Build Path*.

Probably you want to **download** e.g. the file `jwebunit-3.3-release.zip` from [here](https://github.com/JWebUnit/jwebunit/releases) and **add all JARs** contained in that ZIP (in the root folder and in `lib`) **to your *Java Build Path*** instead.